# How do I generate a primary key using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm mucking about with SSIS and can't figure out how to generate a primary key?

I have a very simple SSIS Data Flow:

```
Excel File Source -> Character Map -> ADO.NET Destination
```

The Excel file has the following structure:

```
Field1
```

The destination table has the following structure:

```
ID - UniqueIdentifier (GUID)
Field1
```

There's no problem mapping Field1, but how do I get ID to map to the NEWID() SQL Server function (or something equivalent like the .NET method System.Guid.NewGuid()).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you do is create a DEFAULT CONSTRAINT for the ID field as `NEWID()`.  In SQL Server, go to the table design, click on the ID column and in the properties, look for DEFAULT. There, type `NEWID()`. Save the table.

In SSIS, only insert into Field1, and the ID will automatically be generated at every attempted insert.

Comment: @Josh Kodroff: Yes, I am describing how to implement in SQL Server.